# XMLHttpRequest slow...how to do the same thing quicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, handlebars.js

this is the function I'm using to load my Handlebars template from the file. I found it very slow even if I'm loading local file. In my opinion the XMLHttpRequest() is not very vast for local files. Is there a way to do the same thing with eg. jQuery get() or something quicker? Thanks

```
function getTemplate (name, callback, dir) {
  if (dir === undefined) dir = ''
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var url = '/scripts/templates/' + dir + name + '.html'
  xhr.open('GET', url, true)
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var raw = xhr.responseText
      var compiled = Handlebars.compile(raw)
      callback(compiled)
    }
  }
  xhr.send()
}
```

example of usage:

```
getTemplate('no-results', function (tmp) {
    $(historyContainer).append(tmp())
  })
```

Comment: Can you do a timer to see if it's the rendering, or the request that's taking the most time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this tweak seams to work well

```
function getTemplate (name, callback, dir) {
  if (dir === undefined) dir = ''
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var url = '/scripts/templates/' + dir + name + '.html'

  return fetch(url).then(function (res) {
    return res.text()
  }).then(function (html) {
    var compiled = Handlebars.compile(html)
    callback(compiled)
  })
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) article about Fetch. You can use Fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest().

```
Example:

@meth = GET | POST | PUT
@url = path
@data = {test1: "teste1"}

function ajaxRequest(meth, url, data) {
   return fetch(url, {
      method: meth,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: data,
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
    .then(resp => {
        if(resp.status != 200) throw new Error(resp.statusText)
        return resp.text()
    })
```

}

Comment: would you mind to show fetch usage based on my example?